# Set proxy of current shell within Python code

Tags: shell, proxy, python-2.6

I am using Python (Tweepy library) streaming tweets from Twitter. As our network is behind a firewall, I use a proxy before executing my Python module, `stream_tweets.py`

```
$ export HTTPS_PROXY=https://<ip>:<port>/

$ python stream_tweets.py
```

I would like to know how to set the proxy of the shell environment WITHIN my Python code instead of doing it in the shell itself. Can you also tell me how to parameterize the proxy instead of hard-coding it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=proxy#proxies) in your code.
Both is possible, using system proxy or setting your own parameters like

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/'}
```

or

```
proxies = {'http://10.20.1.128': 'http://10.10.1.10:5323'}
```

for a specific host.